# Is it possible to run VBA macro in phases so that the runtime is reduced?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I am trying to build a worksheet that allows me and my colleagues to fill in variables in a worksheet, as one would do during an intake conversation with a customer. I have succeeded so far, but the macro has become very very slow... I already disabled ScreenUpdating, DisplayPageBreaks, Calculation and Events.

Actually, I am pretty sure it takes so long because of the extensive `Private Sub Worksheet_Change`. I use some initial formatting for when the cell is still empty, so that my colleagues know what to put in the cell. But this process is repeated individually for about 170 rows. It looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Cells(19,3).Value="" Then Cells(19,3).Value="Fill in x.."
     Cells(19,3).Font.Fontstyle = "Italic"
     Cells(19,3).Font.ColorIndex = 16

  If Cells(20,3).Value="" Then Cells(20,3).Value="Fill in y.."
     Cells(20,3).Font.Fontstyle = "Italic"
     Cells(20,3).Font.ColorIndex = 16

  If Cells(25,2).Value="" Then Cells(25,2).Value="Fill in z.."
     Cells(25,2).Font.Fontstyle = "Italic"
     Cells(25,2).Font.ColorIndex = 16

  If Cells(70,3) = True Then Cells(70,3).Value = "Comment.."
  If Cells(70,3) = False Then Cells(70,3).Value = ""
     Cells(70,3).Font.Fontstyle = "Italic"
     Cells(70,3).Font.ColorIndex = 16
```

And this goes on for lots of other cells. I would like to explore whether it is possible to only run pieces of the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` at the time. For example, that it only checks whether a cells changes in the chapter that the person in currently working in. Could someone help me with this, or put me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how can _"the chapter that the person in currently working in"_ be identified? If it's the changed cells, then run code just for `Target ` Range

Comment: You can wrap each block and check whether cell has been changed, `If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(19,3)) Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: Also, if `If - Then` statement is completed in one line as in all of your cases, then the code next to it will run irrespective of the if result immediately above them. So, in your case all statements will be run (including If conditions and others) making the if statements redundant. So even if `Cells(19,3).Value<>""` it will still check the condition and will make Cells(19,3).Font italic and colorindex 16. Better to use if blocks with actions on the next lines and with end ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `If - Then` statement is completed in one line as in all of your cases, then the code next to it will run irrespective of the if result immediately above them. So, in your case all statements will be run (including If conditions and others) making the if statements redundant. So even if `Cells(19,3).Value<>""` it will still check the condition and will make `Cells(19,3).Font italic and colorindex 16`. Better to use if blocks with actions on the next lines and with end ifs

[Worksheet.Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link. This event does not occur when cells change during a recalculation. Use the [Calculate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) event to trap a sheet recalculation. So, if the user is updating the sheet manually, only one cell will be changed at a time.

Hence, every time when a single cell is changed macro will check all 170 rows and execute all the statements irrespective of the outcome of the if statements as mentioned above and there will be delay.

Comment: Hi Naresh, thanks a lot for the help, it made my code run a lot faster. However, I still encounter 2 problems. Before the value (like "Fill in z..") returns to a cell after I cleared it, I first need to change another cell, this may not always be the logical thing to do while filling in this form. Is there anything I can change about that? In addition, I use a lot of checkboxes as conditions, but they too only work if i change another cell afterwards. You mentioned the worksheet.calculate event to tackle this, but I cant figer out how to use this. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I see. I made mistake by just assuming my own interpretation of your code. It seems your problem is very different and hence, both the question and the answer are irrelevant. I think your worksheet is a form wherein you want some default values with italic font and font color and text informing user what info to fill in. I suggest you update the question with a screenshot of the worksheet. Then the problem can be better understood. The code in the answer is irrelevant so removing it.